# Entity Framework as a type checking/verification system for database code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4

When I read pro and con lists of using Entity Framework (or any modern ORM really), I'm surprised that the following point doesn't arise (self quote):

> Using strongly-typed domain entities allows for type checking at
>   compile-time which essentially performs a verification of all your
>   database operations.  This is something that is not possible with
>   ADO.NET (whether using inline SQL or stored procedures).

For me, this is one of the biggest advantages of using an ORM.  An issue that I come across regularly when dealing with ADO.NET based applications are the run-time errors from SQL.  Static checking completely eliminates this.

Could anyone elaborate as to why this isn't hugely relevant to many developers?

Comment: I can't elaborate on a statement I don't agree with. Also, such discussion questions, however interesting, are off topic here.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why you don't agree?  Thanks

Comment: There are many more reasons for using an ORM. There can be many reasons to use ADO.Net. What makes you think _many developers_ don't see the relevance of compile-time type safety? It's really is not a question to discuss here. See the faq.

Comment: Because _many developers_ disagree with me when I discuss this issue.  They don't think of it as a major pro to using EF.  Yes, I understand that there are many reasons to use ADO.NET.  That is not the discussion here.  Sure, the FAQ likes us to have code in our questions - apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question was asked [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186649/entity-framework-as-a-type-checking-verification-system-for-database-code).  It includes some good answers.

[Programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) was a more appropriate place to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's great.

It's also not free. EF is essentially built on top of ADO.net, it just uses reflection to convert back-and-forth between strongly typed classes and the actual column names. This is fine if your recordset is fairly small, but it's very noticeable when you start dealing with larger sets of data. 
Generally this extra lag time isn't important because if, say, the DB takes two seconds to pull the data up to begin with, what difference does an extra millisecond (or even a second) make. But there are situations where speed is critically important, and in those situations you pretty much have to write your own constructs using raw ADO.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question completely.  I understand what EF is, I just want more clarity/opinions on the quoted statement.